# Div with scrolling images

Tags: jquery, css

Having a scrolling div that contains images with remote source.

when I scroll down or up each time images take time to load from its source how can I prevent that ?

Here is my div styling which contains list of images

```
.scrollingdiv {
height: 270px;
background-color: white;
border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(4, 180, 220);
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

and here is the html markup

```
<div class="scrollingdiv">
 <div class="seconddiv" style="height:350px; overflow:hidden;">
<ul>
<li> <img src="remotesource1"> </li>
<li> <img src="remotesource2"> </li>
<li> <img src="remotesource3"> </li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

I hope to find a solution for that.

Comment: What do you mean "list of images"?

Comment: Can you create a fiddle illustrating your issue? It is hard to understand without more code

Comment: I will make a jsfiddle now

Comment: @RemonAmin Is "remoteSource1", "remoteSource2", etc. a reference to a picture, e.g. "remoteSource1.jpg" - or is this a reference to a PHP/JSP/ASP/ASPX script?

Comment: its src for image .,..I am creating jsfiddle now ,,I think its more better to demonstrate

Comment: are the images large? or large and scaled down?

Comment: on jsfiddle its working great but on my site in spite I am using the same code its not working and images fadout out when scrolling and show after i stop scrolling

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9v29m/

Comment: I knew the problem now it was the image float ,,thanks all for help

Comment: google for `jQuery preload images` and you will find many resources

Comment: here is a similar issue with a solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/476681/1807551

Comment: thanks but the problem was in the image float property

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in image float css removing float solved the problem